# Improving the accuracy in number recognition in tesseract-ocr

Tags: node.js, discord.js, tesseract

I recently started using tesseract-ocr with the help of sharp (a node.js image editor). In my algorithm a certain picture is supposed to get resized and cropped by sharp and get the content of the remaining picture recognized by tesseract-ocr. This must be happening two times in two separate parts of the picture, on the first part of the picture it recognizes the letters flawlessly so I will not post this part of the code, it is identical with the second one anyway, the problem lies with the second picture. It is supposed to read those two numbers in the pictures and all it does is read everything BUT those numbers.

```
const config = {
  lang: "eng",
  oem: 1,
  psm: 3,
}

let originalImage = `tmp_scrsht.jpg`;
let outputImagelevel = 'levelcropped.jpg'

sharp(originalImage).resize({ height: 1000 }).extract({ width : 300, height:250 , left: 5, top: 500}).threshold(230).toFile(outputImagelevel)
  .then(function(new_file_info) {
      tesseract.recognize(outputImagelevel, config)
      .then(text => {
        console.log(text)
        var newtext = text.split(' ') && text.split('\n') 
        level = newtext[0];
        message.author.send(`number is: ${level}`);
      })
  })
```

The initial image gets resized and cropped in order to let tesseract be concentrated in the part of the image that interests me. Also, because I had no luck with just cropping, I read that if you put a threshold on the image with sharp, tesseract will be more effective in reading the picture, which makes sense as it converts the image pixels to either 255 or 0.

with all those filters involved, the final image tesseract is called to read is this:

[image: the image tesseract must read]

As I said earlier, for some reason, in most of those pictures, it ignores the numbers and just reads everything else, in some pictures it works, on some it does not, there is no consistency or a pattern on which pictures it recognizes whatsoever.

Comment: I've never used psm 3. Usually I try 6-13.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set tessedit_char_whitelist

From [examples](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/blob/HEAD/docs/examples.md)

```
const { createWorker } = require('tesseract.js');

const worker = createWorker();

(async () => {
  await worker.load();
  await worker.loadLanguage('eng');
  await worker.initialize('eng');
  await worker.setParameters({
    tessedit_char_whitelist: '0123456789',
  });
  const { data: { text } } = await worker.recognize('https://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/img/eng_bw.png');
  console.log(text);
  await worker.terminate();
})();
```